# Linear programming with what I think has 3 variable. I need to plot a graph of the constraints too.

Tags: linear-programming

I have a question.

A refinery gets oil from three wells. Each wells provides oil with a certain amount of lead and iso-octane. The blended product must contain a maximum of 3.5% lead and a minimum of 65% iso-octane. The refinery wishes to purchase a total of 100 litres of oil from these three wells.

The table is: 
Oil Well A: 4% lead, 70% Iso-octane and 21 cents per litre
Oil well B: 2% lead, 60% Iso-octane and 23 cents per litre
Oil well C: 6% lead, 80% Iso-octane and 26 cents per litre.
Amount of Ingredients allowed: 3.5% lead maximum and 65% minimum Iso-octane.

Can someone help me find the decision variable, constraints and the objective function? Thank you very much .

Answer (score 2):

Variables are x, y, z litres of oil from refinery A, B and C respectively. 
constraints are:  
$4x+2y+6z \leq 3.5$
$70x+60y+80z \geq 65 $
$x+y+z = 100$
$x, y \geq 0$

Objective function:  $z=21x+23y+26z$